# How to save/copy value of table column not listed in csv column list in vertica copy command

Tags: python, vertica

I am using following code to copy data from csv to vertica table.

```
copy_command = 'COPY cb.table_format2 (ACC_NO, REF_NO, CUSTOMER_NAME, ADDRESS) FROM STDIN '\
    'ENCLOSED BY \'"\' delimiter \',\' SKIP 1 '\
    'exceptions \'' + file_path_exception + '\' rejected data \'' + file_path_rejected + '\';'
with open(file_path, "rb") as inf:
            cur.copy(copy_command, inf)
```

I have another field named 'FileId' in vertica table and i want to populate it with value of my local variable, so that i can check later that which data is entered against which fileId, and in my future requirements, i also want to save created on date and user session id in other columns too.

Please let me know how can i do this? Either even this is possible or not?
If this can't be done then what are other ways to make sure which data is saved/copied against which time stamp and user session?

Thanks for help in advance.

Update:-
I am using python 3 and vertica_python module to connect to vertica from python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AS` to sql expressions to fields. You don't mention which python module you are using, but you can do it as a literal. Add in a new field entry that looks like:

```
FILEID AS 123456
```

And just get your string to look that way (probably using a formatter, or a bind value).

Comment: I am using python 3 and vertica_python module to connect to vertica from python.

Comment: Now i want to map column from csv to vertica table, as my csv file may have different order of columns in every call.

Comment: should i create another question for this?

Comment: The order of the fields in the COPY is the order from the csv. You are essentially positionally mapping the fields. So if the column is in a different order in the file than the table, you just need to tell the COPY statement what order the fields are coming and which table fields they map to.

Comment: can you please give an example (with code) for mapping. In my case order may change in every call. But name of column in csv will be same. In first call Address is at 1st column of csv, in second call its at 5th column and in third call at 2nd column and so on, what i want is that this column of csv with name address must always be saved/copied in column of table named 'Address', no matter what the order is.

Comment: You have the example in your own statement. :-)  `ACC_NO, REF_NO, CUSTOMER_NAME, ADDRESS1`  is your mapping. Column one goes to database field `ACC_NO`, etc. If it changes on every call, then you'll need to reorder the fields in the copy to match the file dynamically. The other alternative might be to use a flex parser if you have headers (I assume you do since it is dynamic). I don't really have a good example of that handy, though.

Comment: OK, Thanks. It helped. :)